# ASP.NET MVC - MapRoute and User Defined Paths

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have a problem with understanding ASP MVC3 directories system and map routing.
For example: I want some controllers to put them into Admin directory, so way to user editing should look like: "http://localhost/Admin/Users/Edit/1", where admin - subdirectory, users - controller, edit - action, 1 - user's id. What should I do to make this to work?
I have added MapRoute calling to Global.asax.cs:

   `routes.MapRoute(

   "Admin", //

   "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}", //

   new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // 

   );`
,but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the controller and the action from "Home" and "Index"

```
  routes.MapRoute(
    "Admin", //
    "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}", //
    new { controller = "Users", action = "Edit", id = UrlParameter.Optional } //
    );
```